# How to add RTP (Audio/Video stream) to an initiated SIP call (using JAIN)

Tags: java, sip, rtp, jain-sip

I have devised a piece of code to dial a SIP client (linphone) using JAIN SIP but i want to add video/audio streams to complete the task of a video call.

-I want it to be in the same class
-And to make the code simple since i am using it in Raspberry Pi

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SSCCE example and please more details, also I think this should got o http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jain-sip is just a sip library. If you want to manage rtp streams from your application, you need to add an rtp library and probably audio/video codecs to record / play streams.